# BindingAdapter to set a layout fullscreen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

I am trying to replicate, in java, the following code written in Kotlin. It practically set the layout in fullscreen following some logic, in particular the binding takes place on the element `CoordinatorLayout` through `app:layoutFullscreen="@{true}"`.

```
@BindingAdapter("layoutFullscreen")
fun View.bindLayoutFullscreen(previousFullscreen: Boolean, fullscreen: Boolean) {
    if (previousFullscreen != fullscreen && fullscreen) {
        systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    }
}
```

I tried to turn everything into java but I have various errors

```java
@BindingAdapter("layoutFullscreen")
public static void bindLayoutFullscreen(Boolean previousFullscreen, Boolean fullscreen) {
    if (previousFullscreen != fullscreen && fullscreen) {
        View.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    }
}
```

How can I get the same functioning of the kotlin code in java?

Thanks in advance,
Giacomo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that:

- Kotlin extensions functions is provided as the first parameter to java, so here the `view` is the first parameter.
- The `or` is `|` in java.
- Java provides setters/getters instead of directly accessing attributes, so that the setter version of `systemUiVisibility` used on the `view`
- Semicolons `;` in java end of line is a must.

Here is the working java version:

```
@BindingAdapter("layoutFullscreen")
public static void bindLayoutFullscreen(View view, boolean previousFullscreen, boolean fullscreen) {
    if (previousFullscreen != fullscreen && fullscreen) {
        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically `fun View.bindLayoutFullscreen` is passing the `view` like that?

Comment: Should not be `bindLayoutFullscreen(view: View, previousFullscreen: Boolean, fullscreen: Boolean)`?

Comment: @G.Ciardini Yes exactly `fun View.bindLayoutFullscreen` => `bindLayoutFullscreen(View view)` in java

Comment: @G.Ciardini `numbers, characters and booleans can be represented as primitive values at runtime - but to the user they look like ordinary classes` .. [This is a quote from doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html).. So, Boolean in Kotlin can be converted to a primitive at runtime; but in java you have to explicitly do this at code using the primitive `boolean`... Although both `boolean` and `Boolean` will work in your case..